# Bridge infill does not stick to the perimeter

Tags: prusaslicer, prusa-mini, bridging

I'm printing small detail on Prusa Mini with Prusament PLA @ default 215 °C.

Model was sliced with the PrusaSlicer with default 0.15 mm quality profile.

The problem is that when the printer is making the bridging infill it does not stick it properly to the perimeter layer. Making the place where head turned back hanging.

**What may be the issue and how to prevent it?**

[image: problematic tool patch]

Comment: It looks like the bridge infill (blue) is supported by the previous layers (black)?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the ends of bridges must always be supported by the layer below them — not the perimeter of the same layer. Add a feature to your model which makes the area under the end of the bridge solid, not a gap.

Comment: This is really a slicer bug - the slicer should be ensuring that there is something for the bridge to adhere to. You should not have to design your model around guesses about how the slicer will lay out the bridging.